# Can maven plugin (mojos) be configured by java.util.Properties from external files?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

If we assume a maven plugin (mojo) is configured by a `java.util.Properties` parameter, it makes sense to be able to specify an external properties file rather than including extensive project-specific XML in the build script. Especially if these properties are also used in the compiled project, not only in the build.

Is there a way to express properties, in the maven dependency injection mechanism, by reference to external files?

```
<configuration>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <name>dependency.className</name>
            <value>com.dependency.Injection</value>

            <name>dependency.name</name>
            <value>Injection</value>

            <name>dependency.description</name>
            <value>Lack of Dependency Injection Mechanisms in Maven</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</configuration>
```

Comment: not by using the standard maven pom syntax. The plugin you use might offer support for doing that. If not there is the properties plugin: http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/ that seems to be able to do what you have in mind? Plugins read the paramters from the config and often from a property. For example: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#executable (uses property: "maven.compiler.executable"). You only need to set that property prior to the plugin execution.

Comment: It seems very strange that the pom syntax does not allow for complex dependency-injection, to the point that I wonder why they even bothered to include the empty-constructor-injection, represented by <dep implementation"some.class.path.Injection"></dep>. The property file is a big workaround, and since the question relates to developing a custom plugin, I think the most reasonable thing to do, is to handle a File or a URL as optional parameter.

Comment: well the injection framework that comes with a nice concept of resources is spring, but I think the mechanism is based on plexus or guice? What most plugins that offer loading of properties files do is to also include a parameter to specify the encoding of the file. So there is full control in the plugin configuration. That is a bit redundant but well... at the end of the day its not that much work :)

Comment: @wemu Why encoding? That's a violation of specification, and quite certain source of double encoding bugs. "[a property file] is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding. Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using Unicode escapes as defined in section 3.3 of The Java™ Language Specification; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an escape sequence. The native2ascii tool can be used to convert property files to and from other character encodings."

Comment: just for some convenience. properties files in java are usually encoded in ISO 8859-1 - which is a bit unhandy. So some frameworks like spring allow to use UTF-8 for them as well. Or tools like flyway (for database migrations) allow some configurations as well. Since one never knows with encoding... better stay flexible :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally, the answer seems to be "NO". I wont't mark it as an accepted answer however. The answer might change with the development of Maven.

Comment: No it won't and never will. The goal of the POM is to be complete and not to rely on external configuration except `settings.xml`.

Comment: @Michael-O Surely a YES answer would not change this. You could still configure the java.util.Properties using the currently supported notation. (AND files are supported, which are not standalone configuration).

Comment: Regardless of the ability to develop such a plugin, I highly discourage to do so. It makes the entire Maven system obsolete. If you really need to use properties files, rethink your approach or use Ant.

Comment: @Michael-O ant is not an option. :) Consider tasks that might depend on properties used in an artifact being built. Our case is quite simple. We scan our code for text translations (like so: foo.t("Hello {1}!", "world") // world not translated) and dump them to a translation database, which is then used by the built artifact to render localized texts. As you can imagine I'm not interested in maintaining duplicate database, datasource and connectionpool configurations.

Comment: why don't you void text literal up front?

Comment: Are you familiar with GNU gettext? @Michael-O

Comment: Yes, I am but this is primarily used with C.